# displaying questions from a text file using lists

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program for a trivia game where the user is asked one question at a time from a csv text file. There is a point value 1-3 for each question. If there answer matches they win the points for that question, If they are wrong they get no points and it will show them what the answer was. The program will run until the user answers all the questions and then displays the players total. I stored the questions answers and points in 3 lists but 
I am not sure how to show the user the 10 questions 1 line at a time. 
Any help would be appreciated

Here is what I got so far

```
// The path of the file to write to.
  // string filename = "C:\\Intel\\Trivia.csv";
    static void LoadData(
         string filePath,
         List<string> questionList,
         List<string> answersList,
         List<int> pointsList
         )
    {
        try
        {
            // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
            // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string line;
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
                // the file is reached.
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] lineArray = line.Split(",");
                    string question = lineArray[0];
                    string answer =   lineArray[1];
                    int point = int.Parse(lineArray[2]);
                    questionList.Add(question);
                    answersList.Add(answer);
                    pointsList.Add(point);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Let the user know what went wrong.
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string filename = "C:\\Intel\\Trivia.csv";
        // Declare and create three parallel list to store the data
        List<string> questionList = new List<string>();
        List<string> answerList = new List<string>();
        List<int> pointList = new List<int>();
        // Call the LoadData method to populate the parallel lists using data from the text file
        LoadData(filename, questionList, answerList, pointList);




    }

}
```

Comment: Use for loop to iterate thru questionList.

Comment: https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/control-structures/loops/

Comment: Why the new account?  [Having troubles trying to read and display a text file to the console in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59185967/719186)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specific question seems to be "how do I show the user the 10 questions 1 line at a time"?

The answer is loop through the questions and wait for user input.

```
for (int i = 0; i < questionList.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(questionList[i]);
    Console.Write("Answer? ");
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();
    // Now do comparison logic to see if the answer is correct, calculate points, etc
}
```